# How do you set a cookie for a web request in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, http, httpwebrequest

I want to set a cookie value for a http POST request, caqn this be done in Silverlight?

If so which class should I use HttpWebRequest, WebCLient or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define the headers with the `HttpWebRequest`, so it's easy just define the `Cookie` header with the correct value, you can find a little help [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.headers.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

To set the cookie:

```
HtmlPage.Document.SetProperty("cookie", value);
```

where value is something like "mykey=abcdef;".
To read it (key in this case is "mykey":

```
string[] cookies = HtmlPage.Document.Cookies.Split(';');
foreach (string cookie in cookies)
{
    string[] keyValuePair = cookie.Split('=');
    if (keyValuePair.Length == 2 && key == keyValuePair[0].Trim())
        return keyValuePair[1].Trim();
}
```

To delete it:

```
string oldCookie = HtmlPage.Document.GetProperty("cookie") as String;
DateTime expiration = DateTime.UtcNow - TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
string cookie = String.Format("{0}=;expires={1}", key, expiration.ToString("R"));
HtmlPage.Document.SetProperty("cookie", cookie);
```